# add button to 3d model in babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

I'm a newbie in babylon.js and I'm trying to create something exactly like that

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/anatomy-of-the-human-brain-2019-4870387fd52b4706a87b1f3337356579

I had imported the model and add a button to the scene when I click on it the data appear as expected.
the problem is the button in away from the model.

here's waht i did.
https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#JUKXQD#341

is there any better way than what i did ?

Answer (score 1):

The buttons on sketchfab are not 3D buttons but HTML buttons added as an HTML layer on top of the canvas that renders the 3D. on each frame the HTML position is updated.

Something along the lines of this:

https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/debug.html#JUKXQD#344

Notice that the projection is happening on each frame:

```js
scene.onBeforeRenderObservable.add(() => {
    pointArray.forEach(point => {
        // project from the stored picked point to the 2D screen)
        var p = BABYLON.Vector3.Project(point.position,
            BABYLON.Matrix.Identity(),
            scene.getTransformMatrix(),
            camera.viewport.toGlobal(scene.getEngine().getRenderHeight(), scene.getEngine().getRenderHeight()));
        point.element.style.top = (p.y - point.element.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
        point.element.style.left = (p.x + point.element.offsetWidth) + "px";

    })
});
```